# How to disable drag & drop on angular-ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am getting weird behaviour when using angular ui-grid.

Here is my **.html**

```
<div class="grid testGrid" ui-grid="testGridOptions" ui-grid-edit 
     ui-grid-row-edit style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Here are my **grid settings**

```
$scope.testGridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableCellEdit: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
    enableSorting: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    rowHeight: 30,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    enableGridMenu: false,
    showGridFooter: false,

    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```

I haven't enabled drag & drop property but still I can perform drag and drop.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: There is no issue with the code that you have pasted. It is working as expected without the drag and drop. Here is the plucker link(http://plnkr.co/edit/w0hcP8MEzpQK8A1cdE5C?p=preview) that I have created to replicate the issue. I suggest you to replicate the issue on a plucker link and update here.

Comment: Unfortuneatly, it still didn't workout for me. i ll try to create a plnkr.

Answer (score -1):

You may include some drag&drop lib. please check angular.module